# OleDBReader ExecuteReader returns 1 row instead 2

Tags: c#, ms-access-2016, oledbdatareader

A query in my MS Access database returns 2 rows

```
SELECT * FROM [qSales]
```

For example:

```
sTYPE   KILK   WART
-------------------
 HD     100    1000
 LD     200    2000
```

Now, I want to get this result via C#. My code:

```
private static string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+
                                            "Data Source=tgdb.accdb;" +
                                            "Jet OLEDB:Database Password = wix;";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string answer = string.Empty;

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Is Established");

        string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [qSales]";

        using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
        {
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        answer = $"{reader[0]}:\t{reader[1]} \t{reader[2]}\n";
                        Console.WriteLine(answer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER For Exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

but the result I get is different from the MS Access result. It's summarized

```
 HD    300    3000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the same database? Note that in your connection string you don't specify a full path for the database. This means that when you run your program inside Visual Studio it runs in the BIN/DEBUG folder (or x86 for 32bit app) Check that folder for a database and look what data is there.

Comment: My db file places in bin\x64\Debug\ folder. And it's only instance of db.

Comment: This can never happen. Either you are looking at wrong database and c# connecting to another.

Comment: Is tgdb.accdb is the same, or it may be overwritten when building project and loose data.

Comment: I changed full path and try it again. You can see it on video https://youtu.be/Q7HmEFfxAE8

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to concat your string to output your rows?  Also, maybe try to convert the values returned from the query to strings.  Please see sample below...

```
string answer = string.Empty;
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Is Established");
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [qSales]";
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var firstCol = reader[0]?.ToString() ?? string.empty;
                    var secCol = reader[1]?.ToString() ?? string.empty;
                    var thirdCol = reader[2]?.ToString() ?? string.empty;
                    answer += string.Format(@"{0}:\t{1}\t{2}\n", firstCol, secCol, thirdCol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER For Exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ty, the problem is not with the output but with data in DbReader.. DbReader must have at least of 2 lines